# Pandas rows do columns

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have this [hull line rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWKUx.jpg) that I want to convert to this [keeping x and y coordinates as columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNc5u.jpg). I try many things, but I could not took results

Comment: Include what is that you have tried with sample input and excepted output.

Comment: I have try to use transform pandas and try to get every row as list and get each elements

Comment: better to share data than pics. very likely that there are faster and more appropriate solutions than the chosen answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want each row to list do something like this

```
Row_list =[] 
  
for index, rows in df.iterrows(): 
    new_list =[rows.column1, rows.column2, rows.column3] 
    Row_list.append(new_list)
```

df is the dataframe